# RxJS keeps updating when it shouldn't

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am building an interface for an audio mixer using Angular 10 and Rxjs.
I have a service that exposes the mixer as an observable. For testing purposes it updates a value in the mixer object every second.

```
this.mixerSubject = new Observable(observer => {
  const mixer = {
    'dBLimit': 20,
    'connected': false,
    'mixpoints': [
      ... big list
    ],
    'inputs': [
      ... another list
    ],
    'outputs': [
      .. another list
    ]
  };
  observer.next({...mixer});
  setInterval(function() {
    mixer.mixpoints[0].gainPercentage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    observer.next(mixer);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Then somewhere else in the application I subscribe to the observable:

```
this.audioService.getMixer().subscribe(mixer => {
   if (!this.sliderDragging) {
      this.mixer = mixer;
   }
});
```

As you can see, I only want to update `this.mixer` when `this.sliderDragging` is false.
Unfortunately, once the line `this.mixer = mixer` has been called once, the view just keeps updating whenever the interval in the observable fires.

What I know so far:

- This does work when passing a simple value instead of an object (it worked with numbers)
- Using the spread operator or Object.assign() in the service to basically pass a whole new object into `observer.next()` does not make a difference.
- I found that I can completely leave out the `observer.next()` inside  the interval. Updating mixer is enough to reflect change on the susbscriber side
- I tried to use `.pipe(filter(_ => !this.sliderDragging))` to filter the updates on the subscribing side. No success.
- Even this updates the view every second, and I don't know why, since I'm passing a copy in the `observer.next()`, and than I'm changing a completely different copy.

  ```
  this.mixerSubject = new Observable(observer => {
    const mixer = { <big object here> };
    observer.next({...mixer});
    setInterval(function() {
      const x = {...mixer};
      x.mixpoints[0].gainPercentage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    }, 1000);
  });
  ```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: What does `audioService.getMixer()` do in relation to `mixerSubject`?

Comment: You're creating a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: A simple way to test if Ingo Burk's suggestion is correct is to use `this.mixer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mixer))`